# XML to CSV retrieve dynamic attributes only

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

Based on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610551/xslt-1-0-xml-to-csv-how-to-retrieve-headers-from-attributes-and-child-nodes).

We had a change in XML structure, hence the input now looks like this:

```
<EXPORT>
  <DOCUMENTS>
    <DOCUMENT>
      <INDEX NAME="NAME" VALUE="folder"/>
      <INDEX NAME="LOCATION" VALUE="C:\here"/>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <DOCUMENT>
      <INDEX NAME="COLOR" VALUE="blue"/>
      <INDEX NAME="LOCATION" VALUE="C:\here"/>
      <INDEX NAME="DATE" VALUE="01-25-2015"/>
    </DOCUMENT>
  </DOCUMENTS>
</EXPORT>
```

For this example, I'd like to get the following CSV output:

```
NAME,LOCATION,COLOR,DATE
folder, c:\here,,
,C:\here,blue,01-25-2015
```

I painfully tried a lot of stuff, but I have no idea of how `generate-id` works. I ended up with this totally not working XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

  <xsl:key name="fields" match="/EXPORT/DOCUMENTS/*" use="./@name"/>

  <xsl:variable name="Fields"
       select="/EXPORT/DOCUMENTS/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('fields', local-name())[1])]" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$Fields">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="$Fields">
      <xsl:value-of select="$this/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What should I change? Do you have a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is with the key

```
 <xsl:key name="fields" match="/EXPORT/DOCUMENTS/*" use="./@name"/>
```

This is only getting the `DOCUMENT` elements, when really you want the `INDEX` elements. Also, it is case sensitive, so the attribute is `@NAME` and not `@name`

```
<xsl:key name="fields" match="/EXPORT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/*" use="@NAME"/>
```

However, when you come to use the key, you are using `local-name()` alot, but this gets the name of the element (in this case, always `INDEX`), so you need to replace all occurrences of `local-name()` with getting the `NAME` attribute instead.

For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="Fields"
   select="/EXPORT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('fields', @NAME)[1])]" />
```

Also note that when you output the field values, you want to output the value of the `VALUE` attribute, not the actual text value of the element itself

```
<xsl:value-of select="$this/*[@NAME = $name]/@VALUE" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>

  <xsl:key name="fields" match="/EXPORT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/*" use="./@NAME"/>

  <xsl:variable name="Fields"
       select="/EXPORT/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('fields', @NAME)[1])]" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$Fields">
      <xsl:value-of select="@NAME" />
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="$Fields">
      <xsl:variable name="name" select="@NAME" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$this/*[@NAME = $name]/@VALUE" />
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Bonus for the explanations, more often that not did I find xslt answers containing only the plain answer... Excellent!